# get rid of locked Word file on Mac

Tags: terminal, mac, ms-office

There is a file on my desktop called "~$file.docx" and I can't get rid of it.

I understand (at a very low level) it is a lock file for Word, and these files have certain properties. But I just want to delete it. I deleted "file.docx" but the damn lock file remains.

I can't open it in Word. I can't do anything with in terminal (e.g. `rm`). But if I `ls -als` in my Desktop it tells me I have full permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--@
```

How do I delete this file?

**Update** The output of `ls -@e` is the same as the simple `ls`. I just see "~$file.docx". If I try to remove it I get an error: `No such file or directory`.

**Update** Here is the output to the other `ls` call:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 UserName  staff  hidden       162 Jul 31  2018 ~file.docx
    com.apple.FinderInfo           32
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS          16
    com.apple.quarantine           29
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Terminal**, if the actual *filename* is `~$file.docx` then use,  `rm '~$file.docx'`, or whatever the actual file name is. If it's `~file.docx`, use: `rm '~$file.docx'`

The above `rm` *commands* assume you are in the *directory* containing the target *file*, otherwise use its *fully qualified pathname*.

As the file is `hidden`, you can use either `chflags nohidden '<file name>'` or `SetFile -a v '<file name>'`, where `'<file name>'` is the actual *name* or *fully qualified pathname* of the target *file*,  to first unhide the *file* in **Terminal** and then in **Finder** *right-click* and select: **Move to Trash**

Comment: I just want to pop in here and say that I use `chflags hidden <file name>` and `chflags nohidden <file name>` myself, which is easier for me to remember.

Comment: @Ezekiel Elin, yes `chflags` is good and is probably better than `SetFile` because IIRC is is a default _command_ where I believe the latter is installed with Command line tools for Xcode.

Comment: As fyi, `/usr/bin/SetFile` was deprecated with Xcode 6 along as were other tools supporting Carbon development; although `SetFile` still appears to install as part of Xcode 12 additional command line tools.